# EF Core 6 : many-to-many self-referencing entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, self-referencing-table

I have an entity that can include other entities of the same type.

The entity looks like this:

```
public class PublicHolidayCalendar
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion> IncludedCalendars { get; set; } = new HashSet<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>();

}

public class PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion
{
    public Guid IncludedInCalendarId { get; set; }

    public Guid IncludedCalendarId { get; set; }

    public virtual PublicHolidayCalendar IncludedInCalendar { get; set; }

    public virtual PublicHolidayCalendar IncludedCalendar { get; set; }
}
```

In the `OnConfiguring` of my DB context, I configure the relationship as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.IncludedCalendarId, x.IncludedInCalendarId });

modelBuilder.Entity<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>()
    .HasOne(x => x.IncludedCalendar)
    .WithMany(x => x.IncludedCalendars)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IncludedCalendarId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>()
    .ToTable("PublicHolidayCalendarInclusions");
```

If I now add an inclusion with this method:

```
public async Task AddIncludedCalendar(Guid id, Guid includedCalendarId)
{
    var calendar = await context.PublicHolidayCalendars
        .Include(x => x.IncludedCalendars)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
        
    calendar.IncludedCalendars.Add(new PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion
    {
        IncludedCalendarId = includedCalendarId, 
        IncludedInCalendarId = id, 
    });
    await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Everything works out, but if I check the database, it now has an entry in the `PublicHolidayCalendarInclusions` table that has both `IncludedInCalendarId` and `IncludedCalendarId` properties set to the same value (the value of `id` in the `AddIncludedCalendar` method).

I've tried adding a second navigation property to `PublicHolidayCalendar`

```
public virtual ICollection<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion> IncludedInCalendars { get; set; }
```

and configure the relationship as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>()
    .HasOne(x => x.IncludedInCalendar)
    .WithMany(x => x.IncludedInCalendars)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IncludedInCalendarId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

but I get the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I refomulate the model like :

```
public class PublicHolidayCalendar
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relation> Childrend { get; set; } // IncludedCalendars
}

public class Relation
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; } // IncludedInCalendarId
    public Guid ChildId { get; set; } // IncludedCalendarId
    public virtual PublicHolidayCalendar Parent { get; set; } // IncludedInCalendar
    public virtual PublicHolidayCalendar Child { get; set; } // IncludedCalendar
}
```

Then the navigation definition is :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>() // a relation is
    .HasOne(x => x.Child)       // a child
    .WithMany(x => x.Childrend) // with children
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

So, a child has children...  Make more sense if parent has children, like :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Childrend)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

---

What `IncludedInCalendarId` and `IncludedCalendarId` has the value of the root id? The relation definition is :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion>()
    .HasOne(x => x.IncludedCalendar)
    .WithMany(x => x.IncludedCalendars)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IncludedCalendarId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

So when something is added `IncludedCalendars`, on SaveChange the relation properties (`IncludedCalendar` and `IncludedCalendarId`) are overrided with the calendar :

```cs
calendar.IncludedCalendars.Add(new PublicHolidayCalendarInclusion
{
    IncludedCalendarId = includedCalendarId, // SaveChange will override with calendar.Id, that equal id 
    IncludedInCalendarId = id,
});
```